# ClosedXML insertTable formatting and order

Tags: excel, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, closedxml

I have a .NET Core 3.1 WebApp using ClosedXML to export data to Excel.
So far I'm very impressed.
I use EFCore to map my query result to a class and that data gets exported:

```cs
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(data, false);
```

I already figured out I can use the `XLColumn` attribute to control the headers in the Excel sheet.
But I have about 100 columns, most of them can have the name of the property but some need to change.
I've added the properties of the class in the order I want to export them to Excel but if I add the `XLColumn` attribute the order is changed. It looks like first all properties with this attribute are exported and next the remaining properties.
Can I change that, because now I need to add the `XLColumn` attribute to all of my properties?

A second related question.
Most of my decimal properties need to be exported as a currency. How to tell ClosedXML that?
I tried adding `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` to my property but that didn't change anything.

Comment: i don't know if is the same for you but for the second question you can modify the number format of the cell for have the currency format. You can find some addictional info on ClosedXML Doc [link](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Styles-NumberFormat)